# React Native set audio file as default Android notification sound

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm making an Android-only React Native app displaying audio files.

The files all are located in the `android/app/src/main/res/raw` folder.

My goal is to allow users to set one of these audio files as their Android notification sound.

Comment: Are u solve it?